# Converting integers to UTF-8 (Korean)

Tags: ruby, utf-8

I'm running Ruby 1.9.2 and trying to fix some broken UTF-8 text input where the text is literally `"\\354\\203\\201\\355\\221\\234\\353\\252\\205"` and change it into its correct Korean `"상표명"`

However after searching for a while and trying a few methods I still get out gibberish.
It's confusing as the escaped characters example on line 3 works fine

```
# encoding: utf-8
puts "상표명" # Target string
# Output: "상표명"

puts "\354\203\201\355\221\234\353\252\205" # Works with escaped characters like this
# Output: "상표명"

# Real input is a string
input = "\\354\\203\\201\\355\\221\\234\\353\\252\\205"

# After some manipulation got it into an array of numbers
puts [354, 203,201,355,221,234,353,252,205].pack('U*').force_encoding('UTF-8')
# Output: ŢËÉţÝêšüÍ (gibberish)
```

I'm sure this must have been answered somewhere but I haven't managed to find it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what you want to do to get your UTF-8 Korean text:

```
s = "\\354\\203\\201\\355\\221\\234\\353\\252\\205"
k = s.scan(/\d+/).map { |n| n.to_i(8) }.pack("C*").force_encoding('utf-8')
# "상표명"
```

And this is how it works:

1. The input string is nice and regular so we can use [`scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001181) to pull out the individual number.
2. Then a [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001491) with [`to_i(8)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001149) to convert the *octal* values (as noted by Henning Makholm) to integers.
3. Now we need to convert our list of integers to bytes so we [`pack('C*')`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000206) to get a byte string. This string will have the `BINARY` encoding (AKA `ASCII-8BIT`).
4. We happen to know that the bytes really do represent UTF-8 so we can force the issue with [`force_encoding('utf-8')`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001218).

The main thing that you were missing was your `pack` format; `'U'` means "UTF-8 character" and would expect an array of Unicode codepoints each represented by a single integer, `'C'` expects an array of bytes and that's what we had.

Answer (score 2):

The `\354` and so forth are *octal* escapes, not decimal, so you cannot just write them as 354 to get the integer values of the bytes.

Comment: +1, perfectly valid answer. I'm just wondering as mainly a C# programmer, will `force_encoding` really do what he thinks it should do? It seems... odd to let you change the encoding on the fly like that.

Comment: @Blindy: yes, apparently [that's how Ruby handles ecodings](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_string).

Comment: @Blindy: Sort of. It will only work if the bytes really do represent UTF-8 text, you'd use [`Iconv`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/iconv/rdoc/classes/Iconv.html) if you want to transcode a string while preserving the characters.

Comment: It seems Array.pack accepts decimals, but after converting the octal values to decimals I tried `[236, 131, 129, 237, 145, 156, 235, 170, 133].pack('U*')` and it outputted different gibberish. I'm missing something here.

Comment: See mu's answer; he noticed that `U*` is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the correction BTW, "UTF-8 codepoint" doesn't make any sense.