# Unescaping special characters in Git-output

Tags: git, escaping

I need to process the output of "git ls-files". If the file-name has a special character I get unusable output:

```
FRANZÖSISCH.txt -> FRANZ\303\226SISCH.txt
NIEDERLÄNDISCH.txt -> NIEDERL\303\204NDISCH.txt
```

No matter what encoding i try (I use C#) those values do not convert to the characters "Ö" or "Ä"

What encoding is used here and how can i convert to actual file-names?

Answer (score 3):

So here's what I found out...

1. Git uses Octal Escape Sequence:  [graphemica.com](http://graphemica.com/%C3%84)
2. Convertion is acually very easy: [related answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273673/i-have-a-string-of-octal-escapes-that-i-need-to-convert-to-korean-text-not-sur)

Answer (score 2):

Most reliable way to integrate with git is to use binary protocol with manual encoding to/from utf-8.

In your case of `git ls-files` you specify option `-z` to it so that it writes filenames literally as they are (they are stored as utf-8 inside git) and separates them with zero byte.

Then consume with output from binary `Stream` which is provided by [Console.OpenStandardInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx55zca2.aspx), if you pipe git's output to application, or check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4535927/2303202) how to get binary output of child process, if you run `git ls-files` from your application.

Comment: Thank you. What I don't like about git is that this information is so hidden! E.g. for the help on status:
    -z
    Terminate entries with NUL, instead of LF. This implies the --porcelain output format if no other format is given.
and help on ls-files:
    -z
    \0 line termination on output.

Answer (score 0):

The encoding for non-ASCII characters like Ö and Ä (and ç and ø and so on) is a bit tricky.  Git *tries* to use UTF-8 here, but there are issues with combining characters.  See [Git and the Umlaut problem on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5581857/1256452) for details and some workarounds.  Given that you are using C#, you are probably on Windows; I'm not sure what Git has to do to keep Windows happy.